# Resources for NLP

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, reference-request

I am an undergraduate student in mathematics. I have a fair bit of experience with deep learning in computer vision research and am willing to dabble into NLP. I hope that things won't be very disjointed and some of the knowledge can be transferred.

I wanted to know if y'all can recommend some YouTube playlists that start from scratch as far as NLP is concerned, and then gets pretty deep into the subject. I would also like it to have a research-oriented flavor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also check this [answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39078/what-background-should-i-have-before-starting-to-fine-tune-a-large-language-mode/39081#39081).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jurafsky's [Speech and Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/) book is a great starting point.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I am referring to Jurafsky's course CS 124, which is based on his book. After this I probably look into CS 224U/N from Stanford, although I am not entirely sure what's the real difference between those two are.